# Perform previous substitution for different selection with single keystroke

Tags: substitute, visual-mode, replace

I performed following command

```
:'<,'>s/2/digit/g
```

on the code below manually visually selected:

```
return _.round(this.getTotalAbs(), 2).toFixed(2);
```

And it worked as intended

```
return _.round(this.getTotalAbs(), digit).toFixed(digit);
```

Now I want to **repeat** the same **substitute** command on another code snippet manually selected via visual selection mode, with **one keystroke**(if possible).

Comment: You can type `:'<,` and then up arrow. It will show the previous substitute.  Are you okay with any mappings?

Comment: @SibiCoder I do not want to create mapping. I want to use native command   if available within vim.

Comment: You'll have to create a mapping if you want a single keystroke.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you want to do <kbd>@:</kbd> which replays the last ex command.

See [`:h @:`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#@:)

Note that this command can be called from normal mode and from visual mode. Also in this case it is not useful but you can also prefix it with a count.

---

**Edit** In the comments @Antony pointed out an interesting command: `:&` ([`:h :&`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:&)):

- `&` can be used in normal mode to repeat the last substitute command without its flags
- `:&&` can be used in ex mode to repeat the last substitute command keeping the flags.

Comment: Or `:&&` to repeat the last substitution with the same flags.

Comment: @Antony: Cool command I didn't knew it.